# Jquery-ui open dialog from js loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, synchronization, jquery-dialog

I'm developing a web site with JQuery 
I have encountered  the following problem:

Going through an array in a loop, and every value is sent to a function that sends it to the server by Ajax.
On success  a message is generated in JQuery- Dialog, in which buttons and button- functions are adjusted by the values returned from the server.

The problem is, that the JQuery-dialog is only triggered at the end of the loop, so I cannot tell which message refers to what value.

The loop func:

```
$('#List').find('option').map(function () {
    semelO= $(this).val();
    **getData**("Insert_hashala", "Inserthashala", false, "***setAlert***", false, "inserthasala", ["semelO", semelO], null, "RefershLendGrid", null);
});
```

The function signature:

```
function **getData**(procAlias, funcName, empytFields, ***onSuccessEvent***, isAsync, dataGroup, moreValues, onFailure, setDisplay, onFailureEvent)
```

The Ajax

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    url: "SvcSifria.asmx/" + funcName,
    data: dataJsonString,
    success: function (data) {
            if (onSuccessEvent != undefined) eval(***onSuccessEvent*** + '(data)');
            if (setDisplay != undefined) eval(setDisplay + '(data)');
    },
    async: isAsync
});
```

}

The Dialog function:

```
function ***setAlert***(data, error) {
    myJson = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
        text = data.d;
$("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");
$("#dialog-mess").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true, appendToBody: true,
    buttons: [{
        text: textButton,
        id: "cancle",
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },text: textButton,
        id: "ok",
        click: function () {                
                getData("Insert_hashala", "Inserthashala", false, "setAlert", isAsync, "inserthasala", [returnValue, "true", "sumHashala", sumHashala, "semelOtek", semelOtek], null, "RefershLendGrid");
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }

    }]
});

$("#ok").focus();
$("#dialog-mess").dialog("open");
```

}

Comment: I don't get exactly what are you trying to do. But the problem should be that .map, won't wait for the ajax on success to complete. So I think you need to create a data structure base, and on the ajax success do something like addToQueue and then when all ajax are completed process the queue one by one.

Comment: Whatever else you do, you don't need to use `eval`. Just pass the `setAlert` function as a parameter to your handler, then invoke it as `onSuccessEvent(data)`. Similarly, just call `setDisplay(data)`, rather than `eval(setDisplay + '(data)')`.